# Extra Column in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

SlickGrid always maintains a little space in right most side of the header, even there is no vertical scroll bar. This extra space seems like a extra column. I don't want this extra space.

I don't find any exposed API of SlickGrid component to remove this.I have seen inside **autosizeColumns()** method of SlickGrid implementation that available width is calculated by the **availWidth = (options.autoHeight ? viewportW : viewportW - scrollbarDimensions.width)** logic. When I avoid **scrollbarDimensions.width** from the logic no extra space is coming there.

But this cause a problem for **forceFitColumns** functionality when vertical scroll bar is present there, an unnecessary horizontal scroll bar is also rendered.

Is there any way to avoid this extra space?

Hi Tin,

I want to remove extra space of SlickGrid what I described before. I have checked there is no API or property in SlickGrid to do this. That's why I had modified SlickGrid implementation.

Comment: I don't understand - what's the actual issue and why did you need to modify the SlickGrid code?

Answer (score 0):

I use v2.1 and when I set:

```
options = {
    forceFitColumns: true
};
slickgrid.setOptions(options);
```

There is no extra column when vertical scrolling is not needed.