# slickgrid: extra column right side IE only

Tags: internet-explorer-8, slickgrid

**Problem**:  In Internet Explorer 7 & 8 there is an extra column appearing on the far right side of the slickgrid.

I have taken the most [basic slickgrid example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html) and placed it into my application.  All of the scripts, css, etc. are there and working properly.  In Chrome and Firefox the grid renders **perfectly**, even with forceFitColumns: true.

I searched SO and found some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115409/extra-column-in-slickgrid) but ultimately I believe this is different.

Any ideas of how to remedy this?  Our users are unfortunately stuck with IE8 for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question.  There was an extra comma at the end of the script code where the columns are being assigned/generated.  Facepalm.

I was planning to delete this question but another developer that I know happened to make the same mistake; so hopefully this helps someone else in the future.